# Android - How to get the time between the 2 click in the same button

Tags: android

Hi i need help to create a button that at the same time is the chronometer. At the first click the text of the button have to transform into a chronometer and start counting time that will pass until i click it again. The chronometer must have hours, minutes and seconds that have pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using simple logic, which goes like this - When you click the button, the system starts a timer and sets the flag to true. And this timer will start a TimerTask which will start counting the seconds. And when you click the button again, it sets the flag to false and the timer will stop. And while this is happening, the TimerTask will increment the seconds every 1000ms and then update the button's text to show you the seconds as the chronometer.

Here's a little snippet to get you started with.

```
Timer timer;
CustomTask cust1;

boolean flag = false;
int seconds=0, hours=0, minutes=0;

button.setText("H:"+hours+"M:"+minutes+"S:"+seconds);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!flag){
                if(timer != null){
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                timer = new Timer();
                cust1 = new CustomTask();
                timer.schedule(cust1, 1000, 1000);

                flag = true;

            }else if(flag){
                flag = false;
                if (timer!=null){
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = null;
                }
            }
        }
});

class CustomTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        seconds++;
        if(seconds == 60){
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
        }
        if(minutes == 60){
            minutes=0;
            hours++;
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.setText("H:"+hours+"M:"+minutes+"S:"+seconds);
        }});
    }
}
```

Comment: but will this display an chronometer in my button each second passed i wanted to update the button text to the current seconds passed

Comment: I've added almost whatever you wanted in this code. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: when i put your code it gives me error to everything i have below

Comment: What kind of errors ? You need to add other code too like initializing your variables. Are you beginner

Comment: i made it work, and yes im a bit new to android, but its working but when i press the button again time doesnt stop

Comment: I'll have to test the code myself then, I'll put the rectified code again.

Comment: Nevermind bro thank you for everything i apreciate it its working fine. I just needed to put some parts in other places and its fine now thank you.

Comment: I understood the problem, I'll fix. Apologies on incomplete code.

Comment: I have updated the code, this one will work like a charm.